# Possible to add a delay in spring integration DSL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have the following [adapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-flow-adapter):

```
@Component
class MyCustomFlow : IntegrationFlowAdapter() {

    fun singleThreadTaskExecutor(): TaskExecutor {
        val executor = ThreadPoolTaskExecutor()
        executor.maxPoolSize = 1
        executor.initialize()
        return executor
    }

    @Filter
    fun filter(data: SomeData): Boolean = ...

    @Transformer
    fun transform(customer: Data): Message<SomeData> {
      ....
    }

    @ServiceActivator
    fun handle(data: Data): SomeData {
       ....
    }

    @Bean(name = [PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER])
    fun poller(): PollerSpec? {
        return Pollers.fixedRate(500)
    }

    @Bean
    override fun buildFlow(): IntegrationFlowDefinition<*> {
        return from(MessageChannels.queue("updateCustomersLocation"))
            .channel(MessageChannels.executor(singleThreadTaskExecutor()))
            .split()
            .filter(this)
            .transform(this)
            .handle(this)
            .channel("customerLocationFetched")
    }
}
```

And if I understand the Java DSL, the `handle` is:

> handle → ServiceActivator

Given a ServiceActivator, outside of the IntegrationFlowAdapter, I have an option to define a `poller`. Within that poller I could add a delay before the next messages is processed.

```
    @ServiceActivator(
        poller = [Poller(fixedDelay = "3000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1", fixedRate = "3000")]
    )
```

Would it be possible, within the adapter, to add a delay for the `ServiceActivator` (the method named `handle`, similar to the logic I get if I add another channel.

```
    @Bean
    override fun buildFlow(): IntegrationFlowDefinition<*> {
        return from(MessageChannels.queue("updateCustomersLocation"))
            .channel(MessageChannels.executor(singleThreadTaskExecutor()))
            .split()
            .filter(this)
            .transform(this)
            .channel("myNewChannel")
            //.handle(this)
            //.channel("customerLocationFetched")
    }
```

And then from outside the adapter I could just define a new `ServiceActivator`:

```
    @ServiceActivator(
        inputChannel = "myNewChannel"
        poller = [Poller(fixedDelay = "3000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1", fixedRate = "3000")]
    )
```

The reason I want a delay between the messages in the handle/service activator is that the method sends requests and I wanna control the rate the request are sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the `buildFlow()` method must not be marked with `@Bean` : the `IntegrationFlowAdapter` does the trick to register everything.

You can add `poller` to the endpoint spec. See a second arg of that `handle()`. Only the point that input channel for this polling endpoint must be pollable - the `QueueChannel` exists out-of-the-box and you can place it just before your `handle()`.

Comment: Hm... I must be missing something big here. I might need to add the extra step I think. If I try to define a the endpoint spec in the handle method, I just get an error message. `A poller should not be specified for endpoint 'myCustomFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#4', since 'bean 'myCustomFlow.channel#3'; defined in: 'file `

Comment: Oh... It might be because of the last part, with the `QueueChannel`. Did I always have the "extra" step I'm talking about, just some implicit default channel?

Comment: Because it also said `is a SubscribableChannel (not pollable).`. But all my explicit channels I have defined are `Queues`.

Comment: Ohh..... I think I got it! 

I added a  `.channel(MessageChannels.queue("Hello world"))` before my `.handle()` (now with the endpoint spec). And there is my extra step, but I did it with DSL.

Comment: Yes, the framework inserts a `DirectChannel` between endpoint in DSL by default